# Unable to import ImagePicker hyperoslo

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I just installed the cocoa-pod for ImagePicker [ImagePicker](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker), however when I try to import it into my Xcode project, the pod is not being recognized. I have deleted it and then reinstalled it but no luck.
podfile:
[image]

xcode Project: [image]

If anybody as had a similar problem, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are opening .xcworkspace and not project file.

Comment: Clean your build folder, and also just try and compile and see if it works - could just clear when you build.

Comment: Cleaning the folder worked. Thank you!